# Elementor problem -I have a problem in my website?

Tags: web, elementor

I have a problem in my website
Deprecated: Elementor\Scheme_Typography is deprecated since version 2.8.0! Use Elementor\Core\Schemes\Typography instead. in /customers/a/a/5/test.com/httpd.www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5051

Comment: Does this help? - https://developers.elementor.com/v3-2-planned-deprecations/

Comment: You could also see what is on that line in the line referenced. I'm not sure how configurable Elementor is.

Comment: ryanwebjackson In fact, I use Word Press and ELMentor to build websites and ready-made themes, so I do not understand many of the terms mentioned in this explanation

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and reasearched for it alot... What plugins are you using besides elementor?

If you have Essential Addons installed, try to deactivate it and see if the problem is still there. If you are using crocoblocks 'jetblock' theme and their 'logo widget' try to enter following: Dashboard -> Crocoblock -> JetPlugins Settings -> Jetblocks -> Widgets & Extensions -> Deactivate the logo widget.

Else try to deactivate plugins until you'll see the error removed and come back with more information :)

Hope you'll get it solved.